# Excel - How to display information or move on to next column if blank

Tags: vba, excel, countif

So this may be a little confusing.

I'm trying to figure out how to get excel to display a cell's text or move onto another column if that original cell is blank.

In other words, if A1 has "Dog", I want it to display "Dog". But if A1 is blank, I want it to check C1. If C1 has "Cat" in it, I want it to display "Cat". If C1 is blank, I want it to check E1....so on and so forth.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened to Column D? Is it just row 1 you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

I think everybody is overthinking this a bit. There's no reason at all to use VBA. Just use a combination of the Excel formulas `IF` and `ISBLANK`.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(ISBLANK(C1),E1,C1),A1)
```

Comment: Untested. I'm on my mobile.  Should at least show the idea.

Comment: I considered using a formula as well. The reason I didn't is that he ended his post with "so on and so forth". Without more information about the used range, you'd have to capture every other cell in the row.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub A()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range  
Set rng = Range("A1:G2")  
Dim jump As Boolean  
jump = False  

For Each cell In rng  
If jump = False Then  
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then  
        MsgBox ("Contents of cell at row:" & cell.Row & "," & cell.Column & vbCrLf & "is:" & vbCrLf & cell.Value)  
    Else  
    'if A1 has "Dog", I want it to display "Dog". But if A1 is blank, I want it to check C1  
    jump = True  
    End If  
Else  
    jump = False  
End If  
Next cell  

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is one possible approach. Keep in mind, it doesn't break in case of NO entry, so it will throw an error once it reaches the end of the sheet.

```
Sub ShowText()
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim strResult As String

    Const OFFSET_VALUE As Integer = 2


    Set rngStart = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    strResult = ""

    Do
        strResult = rngStart.Value
        Set rngStart = rngStart.Offset(, OFFSET_VALUE)
    Loop While strResult = ""

    MsgBox strResult

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
Range("A1").Select

Do While IsEmpty(Selection.Value)
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
Loop

MsgBox Selection.Value
```